# Effiency of get rows with max value for each group in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Now i have slow query issues when start 10 query connections at same time. below is my sql. i want get max("c") data of t1 group by "a" and "b" and "fb"

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t1 partition(p68)
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT a, b, fb, max(c) as c
            FROM t1 partition(p68) where a=1168          
            GROUP BY a, b, fb
        ) t2 ON (t1.a = t2.a and t1.b=t2.b and t1.fb=t2.fb and t1.c = t2.c)
```

i have created hash partition on "a" field, and each partition have 200000 records,also have index on "a" field and "b" field.
a,b,c is int type,  fb is varchar type

```
PARTITIONS 100


KEY `key1` (`a`,`b`)
```

how to increate sql query speed for this sql? any better ways?
mysql version is 5.6

**now i added index(a,b,c), remove PARTITIONS setting.
table have 20 million records
the query speed is 3s single time, i need to handle 1000 times for this sql, but mysql's Concurrency is really bad, i open 10 connections at same time, each query need 14s.**

**New idea:
 fb field (varchar(513)) really not suitable for index, i want to add fc field which will store base64(fb) encryption, and then i will group by fc field. any risk for this idea?**

Comment: What are the data types of your three columns?

Comment: updated, all a,b,c is int type, fb is varchar type

Comment: `fb` is not part of the key or index?

Comment: yes ,fb don't have index

Comment: You would need to try that first: have an index on `a, b, fb, c`.

Comment: update experiments

Comment: The index is not optimal and might not be used at all. Did you check the execution plan? The index needs to be as I commented above to get any benefit from it.

Comment: have issues when create index for (a,b,fb,c)  msyql reported "Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes", fb is varchar(513)

Comment: But then you have a design issue. You should not have to group by such large fields. Possibly move them to a reference table and give them a primary key. Then reference that as foreign key, and group by that instead.

Comment: could you help to check my new thought?

Answer (score 0):

For the inner query you need an index on `(a,b,fb,c)`.

MySQL can use that index to perform the inner query by finding the max(c) for each (a,b,fb) quickly. See [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) for more details.

The query's performance will become roughly proportional to the count of distinct (a,b,fb). If you don't have too many, it should work very fast.

The same index will also help for the JOIN.

Comment: really thanks, will try tomorrow morning, i have add "fb" field, should i create index on (a,b,fb,c)?,  this index will influence insert speed?   this table almost have 20 million records.

Comment: Yes, it should be `(a,b,fb,c)` in that case. Also if you have columns in the where clause they need to be in the index too. You should get `Using index for group-by` in the query plan.

Comment: if (a,b,fb,c) works, hash partition have any effect? should i delete partition?

Comment: I don't know what will happen with partitioning. You don't need it for this specific query.

Comment: have issues when create index for (a,b,fb,c)  "Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes",  fb is varchar type , now i try to create index (a,b,c) to test

Comment: The only way I can think of is to create a field storing a hash of `fb`, then add the hash to the index and use it for group by.

Comment: could you help to check my new thought?

Comment: Base64 will make the field longer. It will not help you in any way. You can try `UNHEX(MD5(field))` in a  `BINARY(16)` field for example.